# Cannot install git on rhel 7?

Tags: rhel, compiling, git, openssl

```
[root@server14 git-2.1.2]# make install
    CC credential-store.o
In file included from cache.h:4:0,
                 from credential-store.c:1:
git-compat-util.h:213:25: fatal error: openssl/ssl.h: No such file or directory
 #include <openssl/ssl.h>
                         ^
compilation terminated.
make: *** [credential-store.o] Error 1
```

Comment: Please format your text, but more importantly, tell us what you want to achieve. I presume you want to compile git and, because you're missing the OpenSSL dev libraries. Why isn't the git version available from the RHEL7 repositories not enough?

Answer (score 1):

> error: openssl/ssl.h: No such file

Solution

```
# yum install openssl-devel
```